# Do not include lower border on .loc[] datetimeIndex filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following code:

```
df.loc[f"{lower_border_date}":f"{upper_border_date}"]
```

So I want to filter my dataframe on the datetimeIndex but I don't want to include the lower_border_date matches in the result. Anyone has an idea how to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe df.loc[ (df.index)>lower_boder) & (df.index <= uppder border)] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few options:

1. Filter based on index:

```py
df.loc[(df.index > lower_border_date) & (df.index <= upper_border_date)]
```

Directly filtering and taking all indices where index is greater then `lower_border_date` and less or equal to `upper_border_date`

2. use `.drop`. Less nice in my opinion, but should work:

```py
df.loc[f"{lower_border_date}":f"{upper_border_date}"].drop(index=lower_border_date)
```

3. You can also use `pd.date_range`, filter the first date, and then use `.loc`. It's also a weird workaround, but that is an option